# Fluent API one to one relationship mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to make a "One to one" association using the Fluent API. Here are my classes :

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ProfilId { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }
}

public class Profil
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>  
{
    public PersonMap()
    {

        ...

        ToTable("Person");

        HasRequired(t => t.Profil)
              .WithOptional(c => c.Person)
              .Map(m => m.MapKey("ProfilId")); 
    }  
}
```

This implementation throws an exception `Invalid column name 'ProfilId'.`

Would somebody tell me how to set up a mapping with 1-1 relationship using these classes?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing with a 1:1 relationship - this is effectively splitting what is logically one table into two. I appreciate that there are cases when you would want to do this - for example if there were many columns - but it seems to me this should be left as a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring one-to-one relationships,Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key, so you can map the relationship using **Data Annotations** as follow:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Profil")]
    public Guid ProfilId { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }
}
```

Or using Fluent Api:

```
  HasKey(t=>t.ProfilId);
  HasRequired(t => t.Profil).WithOptional(c => c.Person);
```

### Edit 1:

Well, EF lets you create an one-to-one relationship between two entities with their own PKs, but you can't use a FK property, so, remove `ProfileId` in `Person` entity and configure the relationship this way:

```
HasRequired(t => t.Profil).WithOptional(c => c.Person);
```

The `MapKey` method is used to change the foreign key name in the database, but you can't have a property with the same name in your entity, otherwise, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: The problem is that my Person object and my Profl object has each one his own PK (it needs to be like that) is there an other way to map the relation and keep deferent Ids (PKs). Thanks

Comment: That worked for me i only added the MapKey like so :  HasRequired(t => t.Profil).WithOptional(m => m.Person).Map(m => m.MapKey("ProfilId"));